# Catalogsearch problem

Tags: search, grouped-products

If I search some query catalog search displays all products for any query. I cant figure out where is problem? My catalog has grouped products and installed amshopby module. Please, who has suggestions, thanks.

Comment: I assume you have already reindexed `catalogsearch_fulltext`. Have you tried disabling `amshopby` as long as other 3rd party modules and checking if it solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is a problem with the query string (the `?q=...` in the URL) which isn't being picked up by Magento. The is usually a problem with a misconfigured htaccess. Have you by any change changed the htaccess, added a `?` after index.php? If you, that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: My .htaccess: RewriteRule .* index.php [L]. I debugged that Magento picks up query string correctly.

Comment: Can you try and disabling certain modules to figure out if there is a problem. You can disable modules in app/etc/modules/

Comment: try replacing `[L]` with with `[L,QSA]`, here's a short explenation what it does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12551569 . Basically it could be that your query string is overwritten